# Get all the clipboard history as a List in Java

Tags: java, clipboard, clipboarddata

Is it possible to access the whole **history** of the clipboard (hourly, daily etc.) in Java?

After doing some research I've found the following code snippet which accesses the current item of the clipboard only:

```
import java.awt.HeadlessException;
import java.awt.Toolkit;
import java.awt.datatransfer.DataFlavor;
import java.awt.datatransfer.UnsupportedFlavorException;
import java.io.IOException;

String data = (String) Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit()
                .getSystemClipboard().getData(DataFlavor.stringFlavor);
```

But I am looking to get all the values in the history. How can I do that?

Comment: I don't think clipboards store history. You will usually need an external program for that

Comment: Thank you for the input guys.

Comment: Are we absolutely sure that it can not be done?

Answer (score 4):

You cannot. Clipboard is a single value container.

Comment: When you view the clipboard using Windows Key + V, you can see multiple items in the history (assuming you have copied multiple items)

Comment: But those does not come from the clipborad obviously. you can track the history yourself in exactly the same way

Comment: I don't understand; what do you mean we can track the history ourselves?

Comment: You have to listen to the changes, and "build" your history as you go.

Comment: sa for WIN+V you forgot to mention that you have  to ENABLE IT FIRST. By doing so, you are launching a background deamon that will build history from now on forward. It works just like that, queires clipboard and saves its content in repetition.

Answer (score 3):

Its not possible. Clipboard has only latest value stored.

Comment: When you view the clipboard using Windows Key + V, you can see multiple items in the history (assuming you have copied multiple items)

Comment: You forgot to mention that you have  to ENABLE IT FIRST. By doing so, you are launching a background deamon that will build history from now on forward.